# Undefined method, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a module:

```
module Room::Chair

  def get_chair_type(user)
    ..
  end

end
```

Then, I have a class with a class method '**self.get_available_chair**' which invoke the '**get_chair_type**' method in `Room::Chair` module:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Room::Chair

   def self.get_available_chair(user)
       my_chair=get_chair_type(user) # error: undefined method 'get_chair_type'
   end

end
```

I have `include Room::Chair`, but I got the error **undefined method 'get_chair_type(user)'** why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used `include`, so `get_available_chair` is a classmethod of `Store`; and you cannot call an instance method (`get_chair_type`) from a classmethod.

If you want `get_chair_type` to be a classmethod, use `extend` instead of `include`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have defined get_available_chair in the scope of aclass Store. Its a class method. It doesn't have the access to the instance method get_chair_type.